# laravel user api_token is undefined

Tags: json, laravel, vue.js, token, axios

i'm getting the `'unauthorized'` **error** when trying to post a new comment with `axios` ..... i added (`console.log(this.user.api_token);`) just before `axios.post` in `postComment()` method . the output is : `"undefined"` !!!!!!!!!!
 i'm learning and i don't know much about api's . but i don't think user `api_token` is to be set up manually .or does it ???

the script :

```
<script>

const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    comments: {},
    commentBox: '',
    post: {!! $post->toJson() !!},
    user: {!! Auth::check() ? Auth::user()->toJson() : 'null' !!}
  },
  mounted() {
    this.getComments();
  },
  methods: {
    getComments() {
      axios.get('/api/post/'+this.post.id)
            .then((response) => {
              this.comments = response.data
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
              console.log(error);
            });
    },
    postComment() {
        console.log(this.user.api_token);

      axios.post('/api/post/'+this.post.id , {
        api_token: this.user.api_token,
        body: this.commentBox
      })
      .then((response) => {
        this.comments.unshift(response.data);
        this.commentBox = '';
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      })
    }
  }
})
```

api route

```
    Route::get('/post/{post}', 'CommentController@index');
    Route::middleware('auth:api')->group(function () {
      Route::post('/post/{post}', 'CommentController@store');
     });
```

CommentController

```
public function index(Post $post){
  return response()->json($post->comments()->with('user')->get());
 }

public function store(Request $req,Post $post){
   $comment=$post->comment()->create([
       'user_id'=>auth::id(),
       'body'=>$req->body
   ]);
   $comment=Comment::where('id',$comment->id)->with('user')->first();
    return $comment->toJson;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to consume your own api from vuejs there's no need to set the api token manually. Just update the web middleware group in `app/Http/Kernel.php` to include this line:

`\Laravel\Passport\Http\Middleware\CreateFreshApiToken::class`

This middleware will attach a laravel_token cookie that contains an encrypted JWT that Passport will use to authenticate API requests from your JavaScript application.

Read more here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/passport#personal-access-tokens

But, if you are consuming this same api from an external source like a mobile app, an api token will be required by passport to authenticate the request. The token can be created when the user is logged in or registered. Here's how:

`//create a token`

`$token = $user->createToken('Token Name')->accessToken;`

Then add an headers object to axios when making a request to the api

```
axios({
  method: 'method',
  url: 'url',
  headers: {
    'Accept' => 'application/json',
    'Authorization' => 'Bearer '.$token
  }
})
.then()
.catch()
```

Read more here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/passport#managing-personal-access-tokens

Comment: I am trying to consume my own api from another controller using `Request::create()` but it responses unauthorized

Comment: Why do you want to do that? if you are already in the controller you should be able to perform any action you need to.